# Can't Connect my phone to andriod studio or VS code

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, android-studio, dart, debugging

This message appears [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr49Z.png)when I try to run my app on my phone, Hope I can get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you do not have the "for developers" mode enabled because of this it is impossible to start.
It is also possible that you have enabled usb debugging.

[How to enable developer mode here](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/xiaomi/xiaomi-redmi-note-6-pro/developer-options/)

Further in the phone settings, find "for developers". After that, find in this menu the option to debug by usb and enable it.

Comment: Hello Egor,

Thanks for your answer, 
I followed these steps :
USB Debugging
Install Via USB
USB Debugging (Security Settings)
Verify apps over USB

it works now, Thanks